# lower boundary of a polytope

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming, polyhedra, polytopes, discrete-geometry

Let $\mathcal{P} \subset \mathbb{R}^d_+$ be a polytope.
I want to define the "lower boundary" of $\mathcal{P}$, which we'll call $\ell(\mathcal{P})$.
Here's a picture of what I have in mind.

[image]

I assume this object has been studied already in linear programming or convex analysis.

**Question 1**: Can someone point me to a reference that discusses this "lower boundary" of $\mathcal{P}$?

My main question is regarding two definitions I have for $\ell(\mathcal{P})$, which I believe to be equivalent.
To state these definitions, we'll need to introduce the component-wise ordering.
For two vectors $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^d$, we write that $x \preceq y$ if $x(i) \leq y(i)$ for all components $i=1 \dots d$.
The relation $\prec$ is defined analagously.
Here are the two possible definitions for $\ell(\mathcal{P})$:

\begin{align}
A &= \{ x \in \mathcal{P} : \not\exists y \in \mathcal{P} \text{ such that } y \prec x \} \\
B &= \bigcup_{\substack{c \succeq 0 \\ c \neq 0}} \text{argmin}_{x \in \mathcal{P}} \langle c , x \rangle
\end{align}

**Question 2**: Is it true that $A = B$?

I know that $B \subset A$.
We can show this by proving the contrapositive; that is, if $x \notin A$ then $x \notin B$.
If $x \notin A$ then there exists $y \in \mathcal{P}$ such that $y \prec x$.
Then, for all linear functions $c \succeq 0$ (with $c \neq 0$), we have that
$$ \langle c , y \rangle < \langle c , x \rangle $$
so that $x$ is not a minimizer over $\mathcal{P}$ for any of these linear functions.
Thus, $x \notin B$.

The other direction $A \subset B$ is harder to prove.
If you want to show it directly by showing $x \in A \rightarrow x \in B$, then you need to construct a linear function $c$ for which $x$ is the minimizer over $\mathcal{P}$.
This seems challenging if all the information we have is that there is no $y \in \mathcal{P}$ such that $y \prec x$.
On the other hand, proof by contrapositive ($x \notin B \rightarrow x \notin A$) has similar challenges because we would need to construct  a $y \in \mathcal{P}$ so that $y \prec x$ knowing only that $x$ is not a minimizer for any of these linear functions $c \succeq 0$.

I think that $A = B$ but perhaps my intuition in two dimensions is throwing me off here.

Comment: Your $A$ definition looks very similar to [Pareto front](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency#Pareto_frontier), which would correspond to the "upper boundary". I guess you can look at Pareto front of $-\mathcal{P}$ (element-wise multiply all elements in $\mathcal{P}$ with -1) to get $A$.

Comment: Yes, it seems so - thanks for that! I do see that my Question 2 can be reformulated in terms of multi-objective optimization, but it still hasn't led to an answer unfortunately. Any other help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Sekhar Tatikonda for pointing out to me that the other direction can be proved using the [separating hyperplane theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem). In short, the separating hyperplane theorem allows us to, given $x \in A$, existentially obtain the linear function $c$ in the definition of $B$. In this argument, the convexity of the set is the important part; the fact that it is polyhedral doesn't really matter. For this reason, let me re-state the claim.

**Claim**: Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a non-empty convex set in the positive orthant $\mathbb{R}^d_+$. Then,
$$
A 
\triangleq \{ x \in \mathcal{C} : \not\exists y \in \mathcal{C} \text{ such that } y \prec x \}
= \bigcup_{\substack{c \succeq 0 \\ c \neq 0}} \text{argmin}_{x \in \mathcal{C}} \langle c , x \rangle
\triangleq B
$$

**Proof**:
First, we show that $B \subset A$ by proving the contrapositive; that is, if $x \notin A$ then $x \notin B$.
If $x \notin A$ then there exists $y \in \mathcal{C}$ such that $y \prec x$.
Then, for all non-negative linear functions $c \succeq 0$ (with $c \neq 0$), we have that
$$ \langle c , y \rangle < \langle c , x \rangle $$
so that $x$ is not a minimizer over $\mathcal{C}$ for any of these linear functions.
Thus, $x \notin B$.

Next, we show that $A \subset B$ directly, by a separating hyperplane argument to prove the existence of a linear function $c$ we want to use.
Let $x \in A$ be given.
Define $F_x = \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^d : y \prec x \}$.
Because $x \in A$, there is no element $y \in \mathcal{C}$ such that $y \prec x$, which means that $F_x \cap \mathcal{C} = \emptyset$.
Observe also that the set $F_x$ is convex and and nonempty, where non-emptiness follows from the fact that $\mathcal{C}$ is in the non-negative orthant.
Because the two sets $F_x$ and $\mathcal{C}$ are disjoint and convex, there exists a *separating hyper plane* between them.
That is, there exists a vector $c \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and scalar $\alpha$ so that
\begin{align}
\langle c, y \rangle \leq \alpha &\text{ for all } y \in F_x \\
\langle c, y \rangle \geq \alpha &\text{ for all } y \in \mathcal{C}
\end{align}
To continue, we need a small Lemma which we prove later.

**Lemma 1**: The vector $c$ satisfies $c \succeq 0$, $c\neq 0$ and $\alpha = \langle c , x \rangle$. *(proven below)*

Now, we claim that $x \in \text{arg}\min_{y \in \mathcal{C}} \langle c , y \rangle$.
For sake of contradiction, suppose that there is an element $x^* \in \mathcal{C}$ with strictly smaller objective value.
Together with Lemma 1, this means that
$$ \langle c, x^* \rangle < \langle c , x \rangle = \alpha.$$
But we have reached a contradiction because by the property of the separating hyperplane, this implies that $x^* \notin \mathcal{C}$.
Therefore, $x \in \text{arg}\min_{y \in \mathcal{C}} \langle c , y \rangle$.
By Lemma 1, $c \succeq 0$ and $c \neq 0$ so $x \in B$. $\square$

**Proof of Lemma 1**
Obviously, $c \neq 0$ because otherwise the hyperplane cannot be separating.
Now let's show that $c \succeq 0$.
For sake of contradiction, suppose that the $i$th coordinate of $c$ is negative, i.e. $c(i) < 0$.
Let an arbitrary $z \in F_x$ be given.
For any $\beta > 0$, $ z - \beta e_i \preceq z \prec x$ so that $z - \beta e_i \in F_x$.
Thus, by the separating hyperplane,
$$ \langle c , z - \beta e_i \rangle \leq \alpha.$$
However, for any $\beta > \frac{\alpha - \langle c , z \rangle}{|c(i)|}$, we have that
$$
\langle c , z - \beta e_i \rangle
= \langle c , z \rangle - \beta \langle c , e_i \rangle
= \langle c , z \rangle + \beta |c(i)|
> \alpha
$$
which contradicts the separating property of the hyperplane.
Thus, $c \succeq 0$.

Finally, we show that $\langle c , x \rangle = \alpha$.
Define the sequence $\{ y_k \}_{k=1}^\infty \in F_x$ by
$ y_k = x - \frac{1}{k} \mathbf{1}$.
Clearly, $\lim y_k \rightarrow x$ and so
$$ \lim \langle c , y_k \rangle \rightarrow \langle c , x \rangle $$
Thus, if $\langle c , x \rangle > \alpha$, then there exists $k$ such that $\langle c , y_k \rangle > \alpha$.
This violates the separating hyperplane property, as $y_k \in F_x$.
Thus, $\langle c , x \rangle = \alpha$. $\square$

It's worth noting too that this argument works for general conic inequalities $\preceq$.